# How do I add a Gmail username without changing my primary username to the new one?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-management, username

I have a business, and would like to add a secondary e-mail address to my account so that all my business related e-mails head to the secondary address/username.

I don't know how to do that without Google changing my account username to the new one I just entered.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Are you using Google for Work, or just regular Gmail? If the latter, you just need to create a separate Google account.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a filter that would forward all filtered e-mails to the a second account?

First, you must create the secondary email. Add it as a forwarding address in GMail; go to `Settings` > `Forwarding and POP/IMA`P. You will need to open this secondary email to verify.

In GMail, go to `Settings` > `Filters` and `Create a New filter` (this is located at the bottom of the filter list). Provide the criteria for the filter and `create this filter` and on the next option list, select `Forward It` with your verified forwarding address.